# How to add this rich snippet if this is a rich snippet?

Tags: seo, google-search, search-results, rich-snippets

I noticed on SERPs that some of the websites have a little gray arrow and when you click on it you get more information about this website. Some results don't have it. I attached a picture with an example. And I don't know what exactly it is and how to add it if possible.

[image: Google SERP: a result for macys.com shows a box with information about Macy's when clicking on the grey arrow next to the result URL]

Answer (score 1):

*Extended information*

Just because you see extended information on the right side doesn't necessary mean they are using rich snippets. Popular sites are often favored and will return additional information obtained from other websites, for example in the Macy's it has a reference to Wikipedia of which is not something a rich snippet has done.

*Off page signals*

Google uses many off page associations from social media to information sites like Wikipedia to build up a richer search without doing anything other than have good standing with Google and plenty of visitors to make it worth while.